# How to include h/hpp header files in CMakeLists.txt instead of cpp or other hpp files

Tags: c++, cmake, include, header-files

I'm wondering if it's possible to include header files directly in CMakeLists.txt, instead of cpp or hpp files. I'm working on a project, which all cpp files need to include some hpp files. I can add

```
#include "foo.hpp"
```

at each cpp file, but It's preferred to manage the inclusion at CMakeLists.txt level and avoid adding `#include "foo.hpp"` at each cpp file.

I've already tried

```
 target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                           "${PROJECT_PATH}/bar/foo.hpp")
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to include header files in at cmake level without including at cpp files ? if yes, how ?

Comment: No, these are different things. The cmake defines what is in your project. Each file still needs to know its includes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you shouldn't.

You could make CMake issue compiler-dependent compilation flags (e.g. [`-include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-include) for GnuCC) by tweaking the variable [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html):

```
if(GNU)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -include foo.hpp")
elseif(MSVC)
    ...
endif()
```

Although this is **not** advisable as it:

1. is a lot of useless work;
2. make use of CMake (whose task is to define a compiler-agnostic build) to define compiler-dependent compilation;
3. will be a great surprise to anywho reading your code;
4. break IDEs capacity to follow identifiers (think "Find definition" of Visual Studio for instance);
5. is a hacky workaround.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Based on your answer, I will use a `find | sed` script to add the inclusion statement at .cpp files.